# Unable to delete AWS Glacier archive, possible due to archive_id name?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services

I'm on Windows 8.1 (don't ask why) and using the AWS CLI from within Powershell.

I ran a job to list all the archives for a given vault which completed successfully. I then deleted 23 of 24 of the archives successfully.

One archive I cannot delete I can't fathom out why, other than the fact that the archive-id beings with a minus sign:

`aws glacier delete-archive --vault-name MY_GLACIER_VAULT_NAME --account-id - --archive-id "-lai63adP..."`

Error:
`aws.exe: error: argument --archive-id: expected one argument`

Does anyone have any suggestions, please? (other than creating a Linux VM, authenticating and then trying the same command from there).

Comment: For future googlers - this happens on MacOX too.  The accepted solution works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `--archive-id "-lai63adP..."` with `--archive-id="-lai63adP..."`

I found this at https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1135 and https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1409 and more places.

Comment: Yikes, that leads to [an open argparse bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue9334) that's *7 years old*.

Comment: Genius. Thank you.

Comment: Haha, I have never used aws and rarley use powershell. Thank google. Haha. Good luck!

Comment: how is this related to powershell? @Brendan